# Add Items to a ASP Repeater from a Custom Queue Container

Tags: .net, asp.net, queue

I want to use an asp repeater to generate the html for the items I pull back in a custom class Queue. In other words

Queue x = otherClass.getCustomClassObjects();

And then bind this to a repeater.

And on the OnRepeaterItemDataBound

assingn the html values appropriately to what is in the queue.

Is this possible ?

Comment: What kind of objects would be in this queue?  Various different types, or just several instances of the same type?

Answer (score 1):

Okay let us say you have a queue of objects of type Widget.  Widget has three properties: ID, Name, Description.

Let us also say you have your repeater set up like this in your aspx/ascx file:

```
<asp:repeater id="rpt1" runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
     <%# Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID") %>
     <br />
     <%# Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %>
     <br />
     <%# Eval(Container.DataItem, "Description") %>
  </ItemTemplate>
```

In your .Net code you would have the following code somewhere:

```
Queue x = otherClass.getCustomerClassObjects();
rpt1.DataSource = x;
rpt1.DataBind();
```

In addition, here is a link that may help you further:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound.aspx

Have Fun!!!!